# Determine if a mesh is in the center of field of view

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I'm totally new to webGl and I'm working on an Oculus Rift project with Three.js. I try to make a kind of loader: when a user focus a point during 2s I throw an event.

I'm using frustum.intersectsObject(object) and it's work : when the object is in the viewport, the function returns true but I want it return true only if the object is in a centered area.

Here is my code in the render loop to check if the object is in the frustum:

```
// Create a new Frustum object (for efficiency, do this only once)
var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
// Helper matrix (for efficiency, do this only once)
var projScreenMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

// Set the matrix from camera matrices (which are updated on each renderer.render() call)
projScreenMatrix.multiplyMatrices( views[0].focusCamera.projectionMatrix, views[0].focusCamera.matrixWorldInverse );
// Update the frustum
frustum.setFromMatrix( projScreenMatrix );
// Test for visibility

if ( frustum.intersectsObject( loaderMesh ) ) {
    console.log("In the frustum");
}
else{
    console.log("Not in the frustum");
}
```

I tried to use two cameras: one for the renderer and another one with a smaller field of view to set the frustum matrice but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea to make it works? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frustum intersection method is doing it's job correctly.  A frustum intersects with everything visible in the scene by definition of being the *view* frustum.

The problem is you should be using vector/ray intersection.  Create a ray pointing in the direction the user is looking by creating a vector (0, 0, 1) and then transforming it by the view matrix.  The resulting ray is the direction the user is looking in world space.  Intersect *that* with your mesh, and if it returns true the user is looking at it.

Bear in mind that if you're working with stereoscopic content (like the Rift) where the two eyes can actually result in different rays, you should be providing a generic 'head pose' input to the application, rather than relying on the per-eye view matrix.

Comment: I didn't know about ray pointing etc... This is for sure the best way to do it. I will take a look at it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand how can I set direction the direction from the camera in Raycaster( origin, direction, near, far )

Comment: If you have a camera you can get these values out of it.  Origin is the position of the camera.  Direction is the Z axis vector rotated by the current rotation of the camera.  The near and far planes are the near and far planes from a PerspectiveCamera.